# Cooperation e-mail from cloud (O365) and from other provider

Tags: dns, exchange-server, alias, office365

I have a question about usage alias and cloud e-mail. Let's say that my customer have two domains x.com and x.pl. He wants to migrate mailbox with domain x.pl into cloud. But some of his eployees must be in x.com domain and they don't have account in clodu. Did the employee can create alias user1@x.pl (in cloud theres no account user1@x.pl)? Summing up I want to chcek that the employee can use e-mail adress user1@x.pl like an alias when his primary mailbox is in x.com domain on other provider?

User user1@x.com uses domain from other provider. User user2@x.pl uses domain from Office 365. User user1@x.pl ID don’t exist in Office 365. User user1@x.com want to use alias user1@x.pl – is this is possible when domain x.pl is use in Office 365?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking on how to configure a shared address space with Exchange. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676395.aspx for more information on this topic.

Comment: I don't use Exchange Server - only Exchange Online

Answer (score 1):

One of the mail server (either yours or the cloud ones) must have the option to forward mails for accounts on "the other" server. There is no way to tell alien mail servers "mails to this accounts go to this server, the others to the other one".